# Cascade Triggers in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers

I've the following DB structure in SQLite:

[image: db structure]

I want to create a trigger that whenever I delete a country all the related districts, municipalities and parishes are also deleted (like MySQL InnoDB), I've tried using SQLite triggers and came up with this:

**Districts:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [delete_country]
BEFORE DELETE
ON [countries]
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM districts WHERE districts.id_countries = id;
END
```

**Municipalities:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [delete_district]
BEFORE DELETE
ON [districts]
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM municipalities WHERE municipalities.id_districts = id;
END
```

**Parishes:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [delete_municipality]
BEFORE DELETE
ON [municipalities]
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM parishes WHERE parishes.id_municipalities = id;
END
```

I haven't yet tested the `delete_district` and `delete_municipality` triggers because I get a strange behavior on the `delete_country` trigger: when I delete a country **only the first related district gets deleted**, all the others related districts remain in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you use to create the graphics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trigger looks like it is deleting districts whose id equals id_countries, that is, the where clause is actually

```
WHERE districts.id_countries = districts.id
```

You need to reference the id from the countries table. In a delete trigger, use "old" to do this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [delete_country]
BEFORE DELETE
ON [countries]
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM districts WHERE districts.id_countries = old.id;
END
```

Also, I would suggest changing your schema naming convention. Usually, the table name is singular, and corresponds to the entity in a row. I would have a country table with columns id and name, a district table with id, country_id and name, etc.

```
country
-------
id
name

district
-------
id
country_id
name

municipality
------------
id
district_id
name

parish
-----
id
municipality_id
name
```

Then the trigger would be

```
CREATE TRIGGER [delete_country]
BEFORE DELETE
ON [country]
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM district WHERE district.country_id = old.id;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

This will enable the enforcement of foreign keys just like in MySQL. If you define your table with 'ON DELETE CASCADE' clause like so:

```
CREATE TABLE "notification" (
    "rowid" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "user"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "task"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "payload"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("rowid"),
    FOREIGN KEY("user") REFERENCES "user" ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The whole row will be deleted when (in this case) it's parent user row is deleted.

P.S: I know this is a dead thread, but I figured I put this here for the people viewing in 2019. ;D

Comment: +1. While @uncleO answers the exact question asked, you solve the initial problem. This is the correct way to perform cascaded deletion of the referenced entities, since this is exactly what [ON DELETE](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) in SQLite foreign key is for. No need to manually code what can be automatically done by SQLite.

Comment: It has to be noted that foreign key constraints were added to SQLite on 2009-10-14, four months after this question had be asked. So, while this solution is the appropriate one now, it wasn't back then.